# Subdividing a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I group a list into smaller lists of equal length (except last sublist) in haskell?

E.g.

```
sublist 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] -> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
sublist 2 [4,1,6,1,7,3,5,3] -> [[4,1],[6,1],[7,3],[5,3]]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to stick to prelude, you can pull this off using [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:splitAt).

```
splitEvery _ [] = []
splitEvery n list = first : (splitEvery n rest)
  where
    (first,rest) = splitAt n list
```

Comment: or even `splitEvery n = takeWhile (not . null) . unfoldr (Just . splitAt n)`

Answer (score 28):

Try:

```
import Data.List.Split
> splitEvery 2 [4,1,6,1,7,3,5,3]
[[4,1],[6,1],[7,3],[5,3]]
```

Comment: You'll have to install the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package first.

Comment: for beginners like me - that means running `cabal install split`

Comment: Actually, is `splitEvery` still recommended?

`<interactive>:1:1: Warning:
    In the use of ‘splitEvery’
Deprecated: "Use chunksOf."`

Answer (score 10):

The `Data.List.Split` module has a `chunksOf` function for this:

```
Prelude> import Data.List.Split

Prelude Data.List.Split> chunksOf 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10]]
Prelude Data.List.Split> chunksOf 3 []
[]
```

It seemed to be installed by default on my machine, but you might need to get it with cabal.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution that I like is:

```
splitEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitEvery n = takeWhile (not.null) . map (take n) . iterate (drop n)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution:

```
split :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
split n = unfoldr (\s -> if null s then Nothing else Just $ splitAt n s)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but since this seems to be a post for people who are fairly new to Haskell, I felt like posting my solution too. I tried to solve this problem by using Prelude, only:

```
sublist :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
sublist n ls
    | n <= 0 || null ls = []
    | otherwise = take n ls:sublist n (drop n ls)
```

Testing

```
sublist 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6] -- λ> [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
sublist 5 [1,2,3]       -- λ> [[1,2,3]]
sublist (-1) [1,2,3]    -- λ> []
sublist 20 []           -- λ> []
```

Comment: This solution is similar to a solution (adapted from) from 'Programming in Haskell' (section 7.6) by Graham Hutton (on 3 separate lines):
`chopn :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]`,
`chopn n [] = []`,
`chopn n l = take n l : chopn n (drop n l)`

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension uses tails. Since the first set starts with one, all subsequent subsets start with an odd number.

```
 ts n ls = [take n l|l<-init$tails ls,odd (head l)]
```

`n` is the size-of-sublist, `ls` is the source list.

The next one will take any list and include unmatched elements. It is set up to do pairs only. It is obvious how to parameterize it to do any chunk size.

> np ls = [take 2 (drop a ls)|a<-[0,2..(length ls)-1]]

Just include an `n` as a parameter and replace the 2's in the formula, one after `take` and one after `0` in the generator.