# Haskell - Set a limit to the "group" function

Tags: haskell

I need to use the [group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) function but I want to set a maximum limit to the number of elements in a single group and, if the limit is reached, the function should add another list with the remains elements right next to the first one.
In other words, I want to implement another version of *group* that does something like that:

```
groupWithLimit "abbcccddeeee" 2 
=
["a","bb","cc","c","dd","ee","ee"]
```

These should be the types and the definition

```
groupWithLimit :: [a]-> Int -> [[a]]
groupWithLimit (x:xs) limit = ...
```

I tried with map and the lambda expressions but I didn't manage to do it...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Edit your question and add your best attempt at an implementation so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first group the elements of a list, then split all sublists and concat the results:

```
groupWithLimit :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupWithLimit n xs = concatMap (chunksOf n) (group xs)
```

E.g. `chunksOf 2 "aaaaa"` is `["aa","aa","a"]`. You can find `chunksOf` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) or implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the `chunksOf` tip. I think however he will need to "flatten" the end result via `concat`.

Comment: Right, ok. But for me as a beginner I recognize `>>=` as a monad operator. Why did you use it here rather than concat - is this some sort of quick hack?

Comment: @vikingsteve, that just looks nicer to me. I changed the code to make it more explicit.

Comment: Wow, and you tought me about `concatMap` at the same time. Awesome - thank you!

Comment: Your answer is very clear and proposes a simple solution, awesome! 
But how can I implement `chunksOf` on my own?

Comment: @Fossa, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680888/subdividing-a-list-in-haskell) question.

Comment: Perfect, I solved my problem in the most clear way possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The cool thing about Haskell is that most packages are open source. If you go on Hackage, you can look up the source of every function (click on "Source" to the right).

So let's see how `group` is [defined](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group):

```
group                   :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
group                   =  groupBy (==)
```

All, right, so we need `groupBy`:

```
groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
```

Next, `span`:

```
span _ xs@[]            =  (xs, xs)
span p xs@(x:xs')
         | p x          =  let (ys,zs) = span p xs' in (x:ys,zs)
         | otherwise    =  ([],xs)
```

Now it shouldn't be too hard to add a limit to `span` and use this new version in a modified `groupBy`.

Comment: I downvoted, because this answer makes the problem more complicated. A reader is assumed to reverse-engineer the meaning of `groupBy` and `span` and then decide how to hack the existing code. This looks like a puzzle, not like a hint.

Comment: @user3237465: Actually, it shows you how to inspect, understand and modify existing code on Hackage, which, in my opinion, is much more valuable than just saying "here is your homework for you". I've done it myself on a number of occasions.

Comment: Well, you showed the stuff on hackage but you didn't provide a real answer.