# Haskell group predefined length no explicit recursion

Tags: haskell

How can I make a function that groups element of a list into lists of predefined length without using explicit recursion.

For example, for 2:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could use a fold. In the accumulator of the fold (the output list) you can check the length of the last element (sublist), if it is less than the predefined length, append the current element to it, if the length is equal to the predefined length, then start a new list.

Comment: I don't understand the "without using explicit recursion" argument. If you use a helper, it will most certainly be recursive; so what's the point of that?

Comment: What's the motivation for writing this function without explicit recursion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subdividing a list in haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680888/subdividing-a-list-in-haskell)

Answer (score 2):

The following would work (though you may consider it cheating to use `groupBy` from Data.List)

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List     (groupBy)

group :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
group n = map (map snd)
        . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
        . zip (enumFrom 1 >>= replicate n)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner if you set your wrap at 100 characters :). I'm guessing you are looking for something that uses a fold.

```
group :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
group n = uncurry (:) . foldr (\x (l,r) -> if length l == n then ([x],l:r) 
                                                            else (x:l,r))
                              ([],[])
```