# how to transfer a CSV to a graph

Tags: haskell

I am a beginning student in Haskell. I have written a little csv file.

```
csv = ["a1","b1","c1","d1"]
      ["a2","b2","c2","d2"]
      ["a3","b3","c3","d3"]
```

I want to transfer to a graph par:

```
graph :: [(Str,Str,Str)]
graph :: [("a1","b","b1"),
          ("a1","b","c1")
          ("a1","b","d1")]
a::[[str]] -> [String,String,String]
f csv = ?
test = a csv == graph
```

Can you explain me how to do it?TKS

Comment: So... what is your question?  Also, Stackoverflow is not necessarily the best place to get your homework done for you.  If you have working code then you can go to the code review stackexchange and get tips on how to improve it.  Does this code compile?  What are some inputs and outputs for it?  What should the output be here?  You haven't even really supplied a description of your problem.

Comment: I only want to split  a list to m sublist

Comment: I'd recommend you give http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a read, then come back and edit your question following those guidelines.  You're going to get a much better response on this site if you put a little effort into it.  Besides, by writing out a good question with an explanation of your thought process can help you understand the problem better and might help you come to the solution on your own.  That's happened to me personally several times in the past.

Comment: I have changed .Thank you so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subdividing a list in haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680888/subdividing-a-list-in-haskell)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Oops, I missed the purpose of the special case.  Fixed the answer...

Your program is almost correct, but unfortunately it won't type check.  If you're using GHC, you'll get a terrifying error like the following:

```
Fsplit.hs:5:30: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘x’ with ‘[x]’
      ‘x’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fsplit :: forall x. Eq x => Int -> [x] -> [[x]]
        at Fsplit.hs:3:11
      Expected type: [[x]]
        Actual type: [x]
    • In the expression: (l)
      In the expression:
        if n == 0 then (l) else (take n l) : (fsplit (m - 1) (drop n l))
      In an equation for ‘fsplit’:
          fsplit m l
            = if n == 0 then (l) else (take n l) : (fsplit (m - 1) (drop n l))
            where
                n = div (length l) m
    • Relevant bindings include
        l :: [x] (bound at Fsplit.hs:5:10)
        fsplit :: Int -> [x] -> [[x]] (bound at Fsplit.hs:4:1)
```

The important things to pick out of this error message are:

1. The error occurred at line 5, column 30 (which in my source file corresponds to the `(l)` after the `then` keyword)
2. Haskell expected the type `[[x]]` but encountered the actual type `[x]`
3. This happened when trying to type-check the expression `(l)`

Figuring this one out can be a little tricky when you're new to Haskell, but the problem is that you're trying to handle the special case where the original list `l` is shorter than the sublist size by returning the original list.  However, the type of `l` is `[x]`, a list of some type `x`, but your function returns a value of type `[[x]]`, which is a list of lists of some type `x`.

This is a hint that you have a logic error in your program.  In this special case (`l` too short), you don't really want to return the original list `l`, instead you want to return a list of sublists where the only *sublist* is the list `l`.  That is, you want to return the singleton list `[l]`:

```
fsplit m l = if (n==0) then [l] else (take n l ):(fsplit (m-1)(drop n l))
            where n = div (length l ) m
```

and that should work fine:

```
> fsplit 5 []
[]
> fsplit 5 [1..10]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
> fsplit 3 [1..10]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
> fsplit 20 [1..10]
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```