# How to split a list int groups under certain conditions?

Tags: list, haskell, types, split

I want to split a list into groups with n elements. For example:

```
n = 2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ->[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5,6]]

n = 3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> [[1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]]
```

I tried to implement a function, which returns n if n is 0 or greater than the length of the list and the fitted list if n is less than the length of the list.

```
split :: Int -> [a] -> Either Int [[a]]
split n [a]
   |n <= lenght [a] = Right n (take n [a]) : (split n (drop n [a]))
   |n == 0 = Left n
   |otherwise = Left n
```

However, I get a "variable not in scope" error. I've already tried around, but I'm stuck.
Did I make a mistake with the data types?

Comment: I think your question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680888/subdividing-a-list-in-haskell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo with `lenght` vs. `length`, but if we change that there are still errors.

If we look at `Right n (take n [a])` we can see that `Right` and `Left` only accept a single argument.

Your pattern `split n [a]` also only matches a list with a single element.

Let's break this down into smaller pieces. Creating a function that splits a list is straightforward.

```
split' n [] = []
split' n lst = take n lst : (split' n $ drop n lst)
```

```
Prelude> split' 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Now it's straightforward to make this local to `split` to incorporate the checks you specified and return the desired `Either` type.

```
split :: Int -> [a] -> Either Int [[a]]
split n [] = Left n
split n lst 
  | n == 0 || n > length lst = Left n
  | otherwise = Right lst'
      where 
        split' n [] = []
        split' n lst = take n lst : (split' n $ drop n lst)
        lst' = split' n lst
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand what the problem was.